# Change the current directory when a terminal is opened

Tags: terminal, mate-desktop, working-directory

Always which I opened the terminal, on the Linux Mint, the directories which the terminal started is: `/home/user`. How I changed this default directory to another, e.g. `/home/user/Download`?

Answer (score 1):

One quick way to do this is:

```
echo "cd /home/user/Download" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now everytime you open a terminal, it will execute `cd /home/user/Download` right away.

Comment: What I need is the terminal open on the different directory sometime which I open the terminal through menu or sequential key (ctrl+alt+T).  Only this, thanks

Comment: That is what that command is doing, unless I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: When ran this command the result this character ">" I think which the command waiting to another instruction. P.S. Sorry, maybe to my English. I am stilling training

Comment: @EdgarOliveira The problem was that there was an extra `"` at the end of the command (I've edited the answer to remove it).